# Sublime text how to make tab labels display whole characters in a bigger font size

Tags: sublimetext

I set the font size of tab_labels bigger in default theme,so i edit the theme package like this

```
{
    "class": "tab_label",
    "fg": [0, 0, 0, 255],
    "shadow_color": [255, 255, 255, 80],
    "shadow_offset": [0, 1],
    "font.italic": false,
    "font.size": 17.0 <---what i insert
},
```

but unfortunately I can only see the half part of the characters in labels now(only upper part because font seems too big)

(so sorry I dont have enough rep to post image),how can I fix that problem.

Comment: I got the answer...there's no solution now,it should get fixed in the new version in sublime text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible as far as I know of.

You can set the tab_height to a larger value, but it still cuts off the text:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wes.io](http://wes.io/Qzm0/content))</sub>

There is a thread about this on the sublime forum:

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8889